# Change of coordinates in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I want to prove that $$zy^2+z^2y+bxyz+x^3+cz^3+dx^2z+az^2x\in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$$ can be transformed into $$y^2z+x^3+\alpha xz^2+\beta z^3$$ by means of an invertible linear change of coordinates.

I tried to complete the square in $y$, I got $z(y^2+yz+xy)=z(y+t)^2-zt^2$ where $t=(z+x)/2$, but I don't know how to proceed.

I also tried to substitute $x+py+qz$ for $x$ and expand. In the resulting polynomial, I got the terms $3p^2xy^2$ and $3px^2y$ which must be zero, so $p=0$. But then there are also the terms $(d+3q)x^2z$ and $(bq+1)yz^2$ which also must vanish simultaneously, which is impossible. Also I got the term $bxyz$ which must vanish, but $b$ is not necessarily zero...

Comment: This is basically algebraic geometry, transforming a cubic into an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form. That said, it looks too much like hard work to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $$zy^2+z^2y+bxyz+x^3+cz^3+dx^2z+az^2x=0$$ as $$y^2z+bxyz+yz^2=x^3+dx^2z+axz^2+cz^3.$$ Make the change of coordinates $y$ goes to $y-\frac{bx+z}{2}$. This gives $$y^2z-\frac{bxz^2}{2}-\frac{b^2x^2z}{4}-\frac{z^3}{4} = x^3+dx^2z+axz^2+cz^3$$

Or equivalently, after collecting terms, $$y^2z=x^3+\left(d+\frac{b^2}{4}\right)x^2z+\left(a+\frac{b}{2}\right)xz^2+\frac{4c+1}{4}z^3$$

Setting $p=d+\frac{b^2}{4}$, $q=a+\frac{b}{2}$, and $r=c+\frac{1}{4}$, we may replace $x$ by $x-\frac{p}{3}$ to get an equation of the form

$$y^2z=x^3+\alpha xz^2+\beta z^3$$

Both coordinate changes here are instances of the following general fact: If $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, you can control the coefficient $a_{n-1}$ by linear changes of variables. Recall that $a_{n-1}$ is the negative of the sum of the roots: if we make the substitution $x\mapsto x-\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}$, the sum of the new roots is therefore $n\cdot\frac{-a_{n-1}}{n}=-a_{n-1}$ more than the old sum, which means it is zero.

The application of this to the RHS should be somewhat obvious. On the left, note that we're really applying this to $y^2+(bxz+z)y$, as $y^2z+bxyz+yz^2=z(y^2+(bxz+z)y)$.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand where did the term $cz^3$ disappear, sorry.

Comment: I think the absence of the term $cz^3$ is not critical. However, I don't understand your last step. Where do you use your definitions of $q$ and $r$? Also, when I substitute $x-p/3$ for $x$ and expand, I get other irrelevant terms such as terms involving $z^2$, constant terms, and even the very same term we don't need -- $(d+b^2/4)x^2z$.

Comment: 1. Oh boy, the disappearance of the $cz^3$ term is my mistake, but it doesn't matter too much. I've edited and fixed it. 2. The last coordinate transform should be $x\mapsto x-\frac{p}{3}z$. Making these computations is a lot easier when you dehomogenize with respect to $z$, which is equivalent to working in an affine patch on $\mathbb{P}^2$ (which will still give you the correct answers), but I decided to skip explaining that and just use the coordinate transforms for some reason (which lead to this error). I can include information about this algebraic geometry trick if you'd wish.

Comment: Great, now it makes sense. I verified everything directly by hand, but if you have time, it would be interesting to see how the trick you mentioned works.  Also, I wonder how did you come up with such non-trivial changes of coordinates?

Comment: I've added an explanation of how one might think of these changes of variables.